# Proxychains DNS error but not with ping

Tags: ruby, proxychains

I'm having a weird issue with proxychains. I set up the DNS server to be 8.8.8.8 (Google), and I have a valid proxy in the configuration. When I ping google using proxychains, it pings normally. But it doesn't seem to be using proxychains properly.. this is the output:

```
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
PING google.com (216.58.219.14) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 216.58.219.14: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=10.7 ms
```

When I use proxychains to run a ruby script that just runs curl google.com, I get this:

```
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
|DNS-request| google.com 
|S-chain|-<>-208.95.178.196:10200-<--timeout
|DNS-response|: google.com does not exist
```

So A) why isn't proxychains working on a ruby script, and B) is proxychains actually working for ping?? It doesn't have the S-chain line in the response, so I'm having a hard time figuring out if it's that, or if ruby just isn't working with proxychains...

I've googled everywhere about this... I am using sudo, since that is recommended with the DNS error, but no dice.

**Edit**

Solved. Answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a modification of proxychains called proxychains-ng. Works perfectly. No clue what the bug was in the original version.